# Replacing 28.8Mhz TCO with up-converted GPSDO 10Mhz signal?

Tags: sdr

Would it be possible to design a circuit that could replace
the TXCO (28.8Mhz) of a RTLSDR dongle by replacing it with a signal generated
from a 10Mhz reference signal, coming from a GPSDO?

And what kind of components could do the job?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using a PLL chip that is capable of generating a 28.8 MHz output and can do so with a 10 MHz input.

Take a look at http://www.analog.com/en/products/clock-and-timing/plls.html .  The ADF4360 could be a good choice.

Comment: One should just remember that phase noise of PLL might be higher than one of the crystal itself.